# Why does multiselect .net mvc doesn't show selected values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't figure out why the ListBox helper in asp mvc 4 is not showing the selected values. I've been googling and nothing seems to fix the problem. Say I have a controller like this:

```
public ActionResult CreateDetailsMateria(int IdMateriaCurso)
    {
        try
        {
            MateriasModel model = new Metodos.Entidades().getMateriaById(IdMateriaCurso);
            model.listaMaterias = new Metodos.Entidades().getAllMaterias();
            int materiasNombres = model.IdMateriasNombres;
            List<SelectListItem> listadoMaterias = new List<SelectListItem>();
            listadoMaterias.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Elija una materia...", Value = 0.ToString(), Selected = true });
            model.listaMaterias.ForEach(t => listadoMaterias.AddRange(from U in model.listaMaterias
                                                                      where U.IdMateriasNombres.Equals(t.IdMateriasNombres)
                                                                      select new SelectListItem
                                                                      {
                                                                          Value = U.IdMateriasNombres.ToString(),
                                                                          Text = U.MateriaNombre,
                                                                          Selected = U.IdMateriasNombres.Equals(materiasNombres)
                                                                      }));

            ViewBag.ListaMaterias = listadoMaterias;
            List<DocentesModel> maestros = new List<DocentesModel>();
            maestros = new Metodos.Entidades().getDocentes();
            List<DocentesModel> maestrosSeleccionados = model.maestros;

            List<SelectListItem> listadoMaestros = new List<SelectListItem>();
            listadoMaestros.AddRange(from U in maestros
                                     select new SelectListItem
                                     {
                                         Value = U.IdMaestro.ToString(),
                                         Text = U.Nombres + " " + U.ApellidoPaterno + " " + U.ApellidoMaterno,
                                         Selected = maestrosSeleccionados.Select(t => t.IdMaestro.Equals(U.IdMaestro)).First()
                                     });
            MultiSelectList catedraticos = new MultiSelectList(listadoMaestros, "Value", "Text", listadoMaestros.Select(a => a.Selected));

            ViewBag.ListaMaestros = catedraticos;
            ViewBag.datofecha = model.Fecha.Day.ToString();
            ViewBag.hora = model.HorarioInicio.Hours.ToString();
            return PartialView(model);
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Ocurrió un error inesperado";
            return PartialView();
        }
```

And in the view I do:

```
@{
Layout = null;
var master = ViewBag.ListaMaestros;
var matter = ViewBag.ListaMaterias;
}
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.ListBox("maestros", (MultiSelectList)master)
</div>
```

I can see when I debug that my values are set correctly, and in the Selected Items property of the debugger in Visual Studio 2012 I can see the selected=true value, although when I expand the second result view (the one that says that will enumerate the enumerable) I no longer see my value set to true (But I don't think that's the problem, is it?) Anyway, the html markup generated shows no selected property for any of the options. 
Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Following @Stephen Muecke comments about using a complex object that will simply not work, I wondered why is it rendering the values and text fields correctly, anyhow, here's the complete class that composes the "maestros" property:

```
public class DocentesModel
{

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int IdMaestro { get; set; }
    public int IdMateriasCursos { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre de Usuario")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombres")]
    public string Nombres { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Apellido Paterno")]
    public string ApellidoPaterno { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Apellido Materno")]
    public string ApellidoMaterno { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Título por el que desea que se le llame")]
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "El {0} que escriba no debe ser más largo que {1} caracteres y debe ser menor a {2} caracteres", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Grado de Estudios")]
    public string GradoEstudios { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Número telefónico a diez dígitos")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{10}", ErrorMessage = "El teléfono que escriba no debe contener exactamente 10 dígitos, sin guiones")]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "El correo electrónico que escribió no es válido")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo Dirección es obligatorio")]
    [Display(Name = "Dirección (favor de incluir el código postal)")]
    public string Direccion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "RFC")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([A-ZÑ\x26]{3,4}([0-9]{2})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]))([A-Z\d]{3})?$", ErrorMessage = "El RFC no es válido")]
    public string RFC { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "No. de cuenta bancaria")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe contener al menos {2} caracteres", MinimumLength = 10)]
    public string CtaBancaria { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Banco en que tiene su cuenta bancaria")]
    public string BancoCtaBancaria { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Clabe interbancaria")]
    [StringLength(18, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe contener al menos {1} caracteres")]
    public string ClabeBancaria { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Descripcion")]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public string Fotografia { get; set; }
    public string FotografiaNombre { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Página Personal (Opcional)")]
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Url(UrlOptions.RequireProtocol, ErrorMessage = "Por favor introduzca un Url válido")]
    public string PagPersonal { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Dirección de Facebook (Opcional)")]
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Url(UrlOptions.RequireProtocol, ErrorMessage = "Por favor introduzca un Url válido")]
    public string CtaFacebook { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Dirección de Twitter (Opcional)")]
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Url(UrlOptions.RequireProtocol, ErrorMessage = "Por favor introduzca un Url válido")]
    public string CtaTwitter { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime FechaUltimoCambio { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Inhabilitar")]
    public bool? Inhabilitado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Activar cuenta")]
    public bool Activar { get; set; }
}
```

I don't think this is a complex object, it's simply a collection of primitives. @Stephen Muecke can you clarify, because in the same solution, I can do the following with a simple DropDownList:

```
var allRoles = roles.GetAllRoles().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x,
                Value = x
            }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
            allRoles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Escoja...", Value = "", Selected = true });
```

And then the value get's selected alright.
Thank you for your time.

************************** Update with what I've done so far *******************

Following @Stephen Muecke and @111 comments, I created a class like this: 
Ok so what I've done until now is create a new class like this

```
public class DocentesListasModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then I did in my controller:

```
List<DocentesListasModel> listadoMaestros = new List<DocentesListasModel>();
            listadoMaestros.AddRange(from U in maestros
                                     select new DocentesListasModel
                                     {
                                      Id = U.IdMaestro,
                                      Name = U.Nombres+ " "+ U.ApellidoPaterno + " "+U.ApellidoMaterno
                                     });
            List<DocentesModel> seleccionadosMasters = maestrosSeleccionados.Where(p => listadoMaestros.Any(t => t.Id.Equals(p.IdMaestro))).ToList();
            MultiSelectList catedraticos = new MultiSelectList(listadoMaestros, "Id", "Name", listadoMaestros.Where(t=> seleccionadosMasters.Any(s=> s.IdMaestro.Equals(t.Id))).Select(x => x.Id));
```

But still to no avail. It compiles and debugs correctly, but it's overly complicated maybe, comparing it to the examples provided. The problem is I can't design another model right now and I can't further divide in partial views because I'm already using a partial view.

Comment: What is `"mastros"` ? Is that a property in your model, and is it `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: It is in fact a property in my model, it is a list within another class, as can be seen in the line `List<DocentesModel> maestrosSeleccionados = model.maestros;` but it's a bit of a mess as you can see as I'm not passing the property to the LIstBox (it is not a ListBoxFor) I'm just passing it with the ViewBag. But other than that I don't see what may be wrong. Thanxs!

Comment: Your doing lots wrong (and you can reduce you code significantly). When you bind to a property using `@Html.DropDownList()` then the options that are selected will be defined by the values of the property (trying to set the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is pointless. But it appears `maestros` is a collection of complex objects so it wont work in any case (`property `mastros` would need to be typeof `int[]`.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused. First, of all

Comment: To solve this you will need a view model. I'll post an answer shortly (I'll need some time to try and understand your code)

Comment: Ok, I'm confused. First, of all "trying to set the `Selected` property is pointless. I can see it doesn't work, but what is an alternative way. You say I should bind to a `@Html.DropDownList` and then the values of the property will reflect in the selection. ¿What values are we talking about, because I'm under the impression that you can also set the selected properties by setting them to true in a DropDownList? Second, I need a multiselect listbox, not a DropDown List, because that's for single selections. Finally, the value I'm binding `Value = U.IdMaestro.ToString()` is an integrer.

Comment: Some comments on your edit: The model you have shown is a complex object (it as a class containing properties). You `allRoles` `SelectList` will select the "Escoja...." option only if you are not binding to a property. If for example you used `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleID, Model.AllRoles)` and the value of RoleID was say 5, then the option with the value of 5 will be selected, not the one you set `Selected=true` (that how model binding works - it binds to your properties)

Comment: A `<select multiple="multiple">` binds and posts back an array of values (e.g. `[2, 4, 6]` or `["A", "B", "F"]`, not a collection of complex objects, so the property you bind to must be `int[]` or `string[]` not `List<SomeClass>`

Answer (score 1):

May be this simple example will help you :

ViewModel :

```
   public class SampleViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

In Controller set [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) like this:

```
 var sampleViewModelList= new List<SampleViewModel>() {
                    new SampleViewModel() {Id=1, Name="A"},
                    new SampleViewModel() {Id=2, Name="B"},
                    new SampleViewModel() {Id=3, Name="C"}
                };

 ViewBag.SomeList = new SelectList(sampleViewModelList, "Id", "Name",sampleViewModelList.First(x => x.Id == 2).Id);
```

And in View:

```
@Html.ListBox("maestros", ViewBag.SomeList as SelectList)
```

Comment: Ok thanks I'll give it a try, the problem is I'm concatenating three strings to make up what would be the "Name" property, but other than that it should not be a problem. But maybe I can simply use the `IdMaestro` property which is an `int` in my `DocentesModel`class?

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating a view model which represents what you are editing (and get rid of all the `ViewBag` stuff)

View model

```
public class MateriasViewModel
{
  public int[] SelectedMaestros { get; set; } // for binding the selected values
  public SelectList MaestrosList { get; set; } // for displaying the options
  .... // other properties to display/edit in the view
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult CreateDetailsMateria(int IdMateriaCurso)
{
  MateriasViewModel model = new MateriasViewModel();
  // Get the data model and map the properties to the view model
  ....

  // Cant understand some of your code so you need to set the values of the following line
  model.SelectedMaestros = new int[] { 2, 4 };

  // Assign the select list (this is all that's required!)
  var listaMaterias = new Metodos.Entidades().getAllMaterias();
  model.MaestrosList = new SelectList(listaMaterias, "IdMateriasNombres", "MateriaNombre");
  return View(model)
}
```

View

```
@model MateriasViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedMaestros, Model.MaestrosList)
  ....
}
```

If the values of property `SelectedMaestros` match any of the option values defined by property `IdMateriasNombres`, then those options will be selected in the listbox when you render the view. For example if the html generated is

```
<select name="SelectedMaestros">
  <option value="1">Some text</option>
  <option value="2">Some text</option>
  <option value="3">Some text</option>
  <option value="4">Some text</option>
</select>
```

and the value of `SelectedMaestros` is `{ 2, 4 }`, then the 2nd and 4th options will be selected

Comment: I've updated my question with what I've done so far, but still nothing shows up, I think I'm following the general idea of your example and @111 example (although I'm still passing all with the ViewBag, because I don't want to add a property to my already bloated model. It shows the correct values when I debug again, but the markup doesn't change.

Comment: You should not be chang.ng the model. You need to create a view model. Just use the code n my answer (no other properties for the moment) so that you can see how it works. The key issues are that (1) currently `mastros` is `List<DocentesModel>` and you cannot bind a listbox to a collection of complex objects and (2) you do not need to set the `Selected` property if your binding to a property (it just ignored!).

Comment: To help you understand how model binding works, change the view to `@Html.ListBox("not-a-property", (MultiSelectList)master)` - you will now see the 'selected' options, but its a bit pointless since it wont bind when you post back because there is no such property named `not-a-property`

Comment: Ok I get that the binding must be to a string or an integrer, but I still don't get what I'm doing wrong, in my update I bind the multiselect to a ViewModel like @111 suggested, and when I debug I even get correct values when there's more than one option to be selected. E. g.: `-  Results View Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable 
  [0] 6 int
  [1] 9 int
` But I still don't get anything selected. (Sorry for commenting so much, I really need this to get going)

Comment: Alright thanks now I'm starting to understand, I changed the view to "not-a-property" like you said and now it works. Maybe I can solve that by using a form collection or a Request object and solve it that way. The thing was not naming the ListBox like the complex object, as you said.

Comment: OMG, don't do that. Create a view model and do it property (and then you also get all the other benefits such as validation attributes etc). Once you start doing it properly, I assume you that you will never go back.

Comment: Alright I'll post my solution (hopefully) later. It's getting late. Thank you very much

Comment: One more thing though. How can I use the ViewModel I created, because I already use a strongly typed Partial View like this `@model MvcCursosSSP.Models.MateriasModel`

Comment: should I render a partial inside a partial?

Comment: That's an option, and is possible to do, but I'm not sure I understand why you would need to do that. Unfortunately you have a lot of confusing code and I don't understand all of it.

Comment: What I mean is what's the best practice, to create a folder with my ViewModels alongside another folder with my models, and only use the ViewModels for the views?

Comment: Yes, that the best (and common) practice. And I suggest you also look at tools such as [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) which make it easy to map between you data models and view models

Comment: Alright like I said I'll try to do this in the morning, though I don't think I'll do it for all my models though, just the ones that need it.

Comment: It's like MVVMC then isn't it? :)

Comment: I should mark one of the answers as "the answer" but both are correct and I don't want to hurt any feelings ;) so I'll post my own answer later. Tnanks to everybody and thanks to StackOverflow